# ¿Cómo compilar varios archivos JS en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

Resulta que tengo un proyecto en laravel donde tiene Login, Registro y Home. En Home no se puede acceder si no tiene una sesión activa, por lo que debe registrarse o loguearse primero.

Entonces, todo se hace en el `app.js`, pero quisiera tener archivos diferentes para cada parte, sirve que sea un archivo para el Login y Registro, y otro archivo para el Home que es donde está toda la plataforma...

Sucede que tengo como 3mb no minificado en el Home de funciones y no son requeridas para que se carguen en el Login o en el Registro, y asi mismo con las funciones del registro/login que carga el Home.

Estoy trabajando en laravel con Vue.

¿Se puede de alguna manera tener dos o mas archivos para compilar? Por ejemplo un app.js para el Home y un auth.js para el Login/Registro. Asi mismo con los archivos Sass. Supongo que es hacer una modificación en el `webpack.mix.js`, pero aún no sé como es la modificación. Gracias.

No tengo nada de codigos.

Mi webpack.mix.js es:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Solucion cambiar el origen a la carpeta resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí es posible, llama de nuevo el método js y le pasas como primer parámetro otro archivo app.js, por ejemplo app-login.js y especificas la ruta de destino como segundo parámetro.

Básicamente es replicar lo que ya tienes pero con otro archivo de entrada:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/js/app-login.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```